# Aplicación Multi Idiomas - Construcción BD MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día a todos compañeros. Quisiera obtener una opinión sobre lo siguiente. Tengo que hacer una aplicación E-commerce, en tres idiomas(Es, En, Al), ¿cómo creen que seria la manera adecuada para la creación de la BD? Una tabla con campos para guarda la información en ES, EN, Al, ejemplo de campos en la tabla tours : titulo_es, titulo_en, titulo_al, o crear tres tablas, una para cada idioma tours_es, tours_en, tours_al, ¿o guardar un string en formato JSON? que contenga todos datos para cada campo. Ejemplo JSON:

```
<i>
    [{"id": 1, "idioma": "es", "titulo": "Título español."},
    {"id": 2, "idioma": "en", "titulo": "Título en inglés."},
    {"id": 3, "idioma": "al", "titulo": "Título en aleman."}]
</i>
```

---

```
<i>
    [{"id": 1, "idioma": "es", "precio": "2755.00"},
    {"id": 2, "idioma": "en", "precio": "100.00"},
    {"id": 3, "idioma": "al", "precio": "95.00"}]
</i>
```

Tomando en cuenta que no siempre existirán registros para los tres idiomas, a veces sólo habrán para dos idiomas, o uno, o los tres. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hace un tiempo estuve mirando para resolver un problema parecido al tuyo. [Lo mejor que encontré fue esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734542/5587982). Ese diseño no solamente suple todas las necesidades para ese tipo de casos, sino que además, si más tarde hay que agregar un nuevo idioma, el proceso de haría de forma normal, sin ningún tipo de trauma ni de modificación del diseño de datos.

Comment: Excelente mi estimado. Revisaré el post, muchas gracias.